# Find word in list created by xlrd and print sentence

Tags: python, xlrd

I have Excel files with data that I need to summarize so I've created a list called `a_master` that contains all of this info (using xlrd).

What I need to do now is search for a specific word for example `"cloud"` and if it finds the word, to print out the sentence that contains that word. It doesn't seem to work though.

It outputs everything that it finds after the searchable word.

```
for line in str(a_master):
  if "cloud" in line:
    print line
```

Comment: Did you mean `if "cloud" in line:`? Also, `for line in str(a_master)` iterates all the _characters_ in the string representaiton, not the lines.

Comment: If you use `str` and then iterate you'll take one letter at a time.

Comment: What exactly is the format of a single element in the `a_masters` list? Please show some example input and output.

Comment: @tobias_k Sorry, yes that's my mistake. Fixed it in the question. That doesn't work either fyi

Comment: @tobias_k It's a load of sentences. with a few \u and " ", thrown in when their are spaces in the excel files

Comment: "for line in str(a_master)" You're turning all of a_master into a string? That would just mean you iterate over each character, not a line of the file. If a_master is a list of strings you can just leave out the str() function.

Answer (score 2):

If `a_master` is a list as you said, probably this is what you want:

```
for line in a_master:
  str_line = str(line)
  if "cloud" in str_line:
    print str_line
```